# Taylor-series expansion of $f(z) = (1+z^2)$cosh($z$)

Tags: calculus, analysis

During my analysis 1 exam today, our professor gave us this question [(german) picture of the question in the exam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85V4b.png) I have only ever seen Taylor series expansion given a degree e.g.: evaluate the Taylor series of
sin(x) for $n=2$ and $a=0$, but in this example I was given neither a point to evaluate the Taylor series nor a degree for how often i should derive the inital function.
I am really puzzled on what I was supposed to do here?

Comment: You're supposed to provide the coefficient $a_n$ for all $n$ where $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$. For example, if $g(z) = e^z$, you would say that $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$. And presumably, you're around $z=0$ if nothing more is said.

Comment: What is the definition of $\cosh$? Do you know the power series for the parts of $\cosh$?

Comment: in our textbook the definition of cosh(z) is just:
cosh(z) = $\frac{e^z + e^{-z}}{2}$
and similarly 
sinh(z) = $\frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2}$

Comment: What you are referring to is *Taylor polynomials* and not Taylor series. The series is what the sequence of polynomials approaches when the number of terms goes to infinity. You can compute it by applying the formula $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(z-a)}{n!}$, or by writing down the expansions of both functions, multiplying and collecting like terms. In your case, the first function is a polynomial, so you can use the second method with the expansion $\cosh z = \sum\limits_{n\ge 0} \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}$  to get what you want.